# Why can't I find a paramter of Application passed to CheeseViewModel?

Tags: kotlin

The following code is from the architecture-components-samples project, you can see [it](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/PagingSample/app/src/main/java/paging/android/example/com/pagingsample/MainActivity.kt).

The class `CheeseViewModel` accept a paramter of `Application`, I need pass a  paramter of `Application` to create the object.

But I can't find any paramter of `Application` in the project to instance the class, could you tell me why?

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val viewModel by viewModels<CheeseViewModel>()
    ...
}
```

**CheeseViewModel.kt**

```
class CheeseViewModel(app: Application) : AndroidViewModel(app) {
    val dao = CheeseDb.get(app).cheeseDao()

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Did you try running the example? Because it seems like you're asking a number of questions about the sample, without even importing the code...*

**`Application` represents your application instance.**

Providing it to the `CheeseViewModel` is handled automatically by the `viewModels<CheeseViewModel>()` delegate.

Answer (score 1):

`MainActivity` extends `AppCompatActivity` which extends `Activity` which has the [`getApplication()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#getApplication()) (usable as `application` property in Kotlin).